# Exterior derivative on surfaces

Tags: differential-forms, surfaces, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I am studying exterior derivatives and a professor wrote the $r+1$-form:

> $d(\varphi^*\omega)$, where $\omega$ is an $r$-form in $S$ and $\varphi:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \varphi(U)\subset S$ a parameterization.

I understand a little about what $d(\varphi^*\omega)$ is: $\varphi^*\omega$ is a $r$-form in $U$ and $d(\varphi^*\omega)$ its exterior differential, an $r+1$-form at $U$. But $d(\varphi^*\omega)$ takes values at $\wedge_{r+1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Could you explain a little bit more about all of these things?

In fact, forms are a little confused to me.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\omega$ is an $r$-form on $S$.

$\varphi^*\omega$ is an $r$-form on $U$ and is $\omega$ expressed in the coordinates given by $(U, \varphi)$.

$d(\varphi^*\omega)$ is the exterior derivative of $\varphi^*\omega$ and is therefore a $(r+1)$-form on $U$. If $\varphi^*\omega = w_{i_1\cdots i_r} dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_r}$ then 
$$
d(\varphi^*\omega) = \partial_{i_{r+1}}w_{i_1\cdots i_r} dx^{i_{r+1}} \wedge dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_r}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! A little doubt: why did you wrote only $\partial i_{r+1}$ instead of a sum in all $\partial i_{j}$ s.t. $j\neq 1,2,\cdots, r$?

Comment: @Na'omi. I use the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), i.e. there is an implicit summation over $i_1, \ldots, i_{r+1} = 1, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Thank you so much.